# Google Cardboard Magnet Refresh Not Working in Unity3d

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am working on a Unity project using google cardboard, basing my design on [Cardboard Catapult](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.schoendevelopment.cardboardcatapult&hl=engoogle),  cardboard magnet to make a ball jump and it works the first time, but whenever the game restarts, using Application.LoadLevel(), the ball doesn’t jump anymore; it just glitches. I [used this script](https://github.com/theqwertman/UnityCardboardTrigger/blob/develop/MagnetSensor.cs). I have tested this script (Magnet Sensor Script) with a test application where whenever the magnet is pulled, the text will change color and it works all the time. Here’s my Ball Control Script (the script I called the Magnet Sensing):

```
#pragma strict
var rotationSpeed = 100;
var jumpHeight = 8;
var Hit01 : AudioClip;
var Hit02 : AudioClip;
var Hit03 : AudioClip;
var distToGround : float;

function Start () {
    // Getting the distance from the center to the ground.
    distToGround = collider.bounds.extents.y;
}

function Update ()
{
    //Handle ball rotation.
    var rotation : float = Input.GetAxis(“Horizontal”) * rotationSpeed;
    rotation *= Time.deltaTime;
    rigidbody.AddRelativeTorque (Vector3.back * rotation);
    MagnetSensor.OnMagnetPull += JumpOnMagnet;    //important
}

function JumpOnMagnet () {   //important
    rigidbody.velocity.y = jumpHeight;    //important
}    //important

function IsGrounded () : boolean { //Check if we are on the ground. Return true if we are else return null.
    return Physics.Raycast(transform.position, -Vector3.up, distToGround + 0.1);
}

function OnCollisionEnter () {
    var theHit = Random.Range(0, 3);
    if (theHit == 0)
    {
        audio.clip = Hit01;
    }
    else if (theHit == 1)
    {
        audio.clip = Hit02;
    }
    else {
        audio.clip = Hit03;
    }
    audio.pitch = Random.Range (0.9,1.1);
    audio.Play();
}
```

Here’s my script for the restart:

```
#pragma strict
var maxFallDistance = -10;
private var isRestarting = false;
var level : String;
var GameOverSound : AudioClip;

function Update ()
{
    if (transform.position.y <= maxFallDistance)
    {
        if (isRestarting == false)
        {
            RestartLevel();
        }
    }
}

function RestartLevel () {
    isRestarting = true;
    audio.pitch = 1;
    audio.clip = GameOverSound;
    audio.Play();
    yield WaitForSeconds (audio.clip.length);
    Application.LoadLevel(level);
}
```

Please let me know what the possible issues could be and how I can fix them. Also, I’d appreciate if you can point me to any website or resource that can help.

Comment: Please format your code properly and state at least one question.

Answer (score 0):

Don't do `MagnetSensor.OnMagnetPull += JumpOnMagnet;` in the Update() function.  Call it in Start(), so it is only added once.

Also, you should add an OnDestroy() function and call `MagnetSensor.OnMagnetPull -= JumpOnMagnet;` in it.

Comment: I am also a novice, so could you tell me why I should put OnDestroy() function.

Comment: The `MagnetSensor.OnMagnetPull` event is static, so it survives across level loads.But your gameobject from the current level will get destroyed (freed) when the new level is loaded.  That leaves a reference in the static event to a destroyed object.  The `OnDestroy()` method lets you clean up such references to your object before it gets destroyed.